# My SQL Create a row with data that have same id

Tags: mysql, sql

So after checking multiples forums and similar questions i didnt manage to find one that is quite what i am looking for.

I have 2 tables:

```
questions            answers
+-----+---------+    +------+------+---------+
| id_q| question|    | id_q | id_a | answer  |
+=====+=========+    +======+======+=========+
|  1  |question1|    |   1  |   1  | answer1 |
+-----+---------+    +------+------+---------+
|  2  |question2|    |   1  |   2  | answer2 |
+-----+---------+    +------+------+---------+
                     |   2  |   3  | answer3 |
                     +------+------+---------+
                     |   2  |   4  | answer4 |
                     +------+------+---------+
```

And was trying to get something like this:

```
+-----+---------+---------+---------+
| id_q| question| answer  | answer2 |
+=====+=========+=========+=========+
|  1  |question1| answer1 | answer2 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+
|  2  |question2| answer3 | answer4 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+
```

Already tryed:

```
SELECT questions.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(answers.answer SEPARATOR ' ; ') AS answers
FROM questions
LEFT OUTER JOIN answers ON questions.id_q = answers.id_q
GROUP BY questions.id_q
```

But this gives me:

```
+-----+---------+-------------------+
| id_q| question|       answers     |
+=====+=========+===================+
|  1  |question1| answer1 ; answer2 |
+-----+---------+-------------------+
|  2  |question2| answer3 ; answer4 |
+-----+---------+-------------------+
```

Dont know if its even possivel to achieve what i am trying. Any ideias?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to have more than 2 answers for a question ? If yes, then this is basically a Pivot Table problem.

Comment: You need to do pivot in your SQL.

Google "SQL pivot".

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `correlated subqueries` with the contribution of `mod` function :

```
SELECT q.id_q, q.question,
   ( SELECT a1.answer 
       FROM answers a1 
      WHERE a1.id_q = q.id_q 
        AND mod(a1.id_a,2) = 1 ) AS answer,
   ( SELECT a2.answer 
       FROM answers a2 
      WHERE a2.id_q = q.id_q 
        AND mod(a2.id_a,2) = 0 ) AS answer2
  FROM questions q
  LEFT OUTER JOIN answers a ON q.id_q = a.id_q
 GROUP BY q.id_q, q.question;

+-----+---------+---------+---------+
| id_q| question| answer  | answer2 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+
|  1  |question1| answer1 | answer2 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+
|  2  |question2| answer3 | answer4 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/RRGN86021)

Comment: It's exactly that! Thanks a ton for the help.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to self join the answers table:

```
SELECT questions.id_q, questions.question, a.answer1, a.answer2 FROM questions
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT answers.id_q, answers.answer AS answer1, answers_1.answer AS answer2 
FROM answers INNER JOIN answers AS answers_1 
ON answers.id_q = answers_1.id_q AND answers.id_a < answers_1.id_a) AS a
ON a.id_q = questions.id_q
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ID,QUES,ANS1,ANS2
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID,A.QUES,A.ANS ANS1,B.ANS ANS2
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY A.ID ,A.ANS ,B.ANS) RN
 FROM (
SELECT ID,IDQ,QUES,ANS
 FROM MY_TEMP_TABLE1 TEM1
INNER JOIN MY_TEMP_TABLE TEM
ON TEM1.IDQ=TEM.ID
) A
INNER JOIN (
SELECT ID,IDQ,QUES,ANS
 FROM MY_TEMP_TABLE1 TEM1
INNER JOIN MY_TEMP_TABLE TEM
ON TEM1.IDQ=TEM.ID 
) B
ON A.ID=B.ID
WHERE A.ANS<>B.ANS
)
WHERE RN=1
;
```

Comment: CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MY_TEMP_TABLE1 (
  IDQ    NUMBER,
  IDA  NUMBER,
  ANS VARCHAR(20)
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE MY_TEMP_TABLE (
  ID    NUMBER,
  QUES VARCHAR(20)
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
;

Comment: INSERT INTO MY_TEMP_TABLE1 VALUES (1, 1,'a1');                                   
INSERT INTO MY_TEMP_TABLE1 VALUES (1, 2,'a2');                                  
INSERT INTO MY_TEMP_TABLE1 VALUES (2, 3,'a3');                                  
INSERT INTO MY_TEMP_TABLE1 VALUES (2, 4,'a4');
INSERT INTO MY_TEMP_TABLE VALUES (1,'Q1');
INSERT INTO MY_TEMP_TABLE VALUES (2,'Q2');